Is there an API or solution to extract bitly data?
I am using this reference:
https://dev.bitly.com/api-reference/
But I can't find how to extract all the custom bitlinks created with a link click for each day?
Is there a way in the API or any solution for it?
I can extract the summary but not something how it performs each day.
I hope experts in API can help me.
